# How to display multiple lat/long geo points on map with a custom text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

Hi i am trying to display certain geo points on the map with a text. So far i have been able to display user current location i am also new to the iphone so can you please direct me.

to get an idea i want it to be some wat like Bird's Eye app

http://www.engadget.com/2011/07/26/birds-eye-ipad-app-lets-you-use-twitter-while-looking-down-on-i/

can u please help me out...

thnx a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this tutorial:
[Link](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/08/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-3/)

Comment: Thnx for the link also can i store the text entered by user and will this help in showing multiple locations on map. which r alao entered by the user..